# Refrigerator 60 Hz vs 50 Hz

Tags: electronic-items, power

Would a 120 volt single phase 60 Hz refrigerator be able to run on a 120 volt single phase 50 Hz power cycle without running into any issues?

Comment: The answer to the question as posted is probably _'it depends'_. You might get a better answer on [electronics.se], but only if you can post a photograph of any power rating label you can find on the refrigerator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about traveling within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @choster I always travel with my refrigerator, don't you?  The real art is in getting the gate staff to allow you to carry it on so you don't have to pay excess baggage fees!

Comment: @Doc [Tony](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23316.Round_Ireland_with_a_Fridge), is that you?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Table_of_mains_voltages,_frequencies,_and_plugs), nowhere on earth has 120V 50Hz. Barbados and Bolivia have 115V 50Hz; Bonaire, Curaçao, Libya Madagascar and Morocco have 127V 50Hz. But everywhere that has 120V has it at 60Hz.

Comment: @DavidRicherby All true, but it's relatively easy and cheap to drop voltage from 240v 50Hz across a transformer. A frequency change takes a lot more effort.

Comment: @ReddHerring True but you need a pretty beefy transformer to run a refrigerator.

Comment: [Here's some basic information.](http://www.50hz60hz.com/60hz-motor-running-on-50hz-power-supply.html) TLDR: don't do it unless you're an electric engineer.